# How to select nearest ineger, thats bigger than value you've got

Tags: php, mysql, select

How to select nearest integer, thats bigger than value you've got? 
How to make it in request?

Comment: Use Increment operator eg. `$i++`

Comment: Value you've got where?  `$val +1`?

Comment: Not necessarily, this value is auto increment. There can be deleted rows, so something like that $val +rand()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable 
WHERE yourColumn > yourInt 
ORDER BY yourColumn
LIMIT 1
```

this will select the first bigger number over yours

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it helped by checking the white check beside the answer.  Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the following will work for positive integers:

```
$next_num = intval($your_num) + 1;
```

Comment: @user1387725: What request?  What are you talking about?

Comment: he's talking about the sql query

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `ceil()` function should do this for you

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

Comment: `ceil()` will get you the next highest integer if your current number *isn't* an integer.

Comment: Whoops. Looks like it pays to read the question properly, doh!